# Why doesn't this second code work in which i try to insert the elements inside the 2d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Problems with 2D array.

This code works but the other code(below this) does not, when i try to insert the elements in the array.

```
`int [][] array = {  {1,2,3},   
        {4,5,6},   
        {7,8,9},    
        {0}        
     };
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(array[i][j]);
}
   System.out.println(); 
}`
```

This code does not work.

```
`int [][] arr;      
    array[0][0] = 1;
    array[0][1] = 10;
    array[0][2] = 100;
    array[1][1] = 99;
    array[1][2] = 123;
    array[1][0] = 177;
    array[2][1] = 999;
    array[2][2] = 453;
    array[3][0] = 000;
    array[3][1] = 1090;
    array[3][2] = 1202;`

    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < arr[x].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(arr[x][y]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This are the errors that i get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The local variable arr may not have been initialized
The local variable arr may not have been initialized
The local variable arr may not have been initialized

Comment: What's `array`? What's `arr`?

Comment: array is the int data type array name.

Comment: this code works in c++ (Inserting elements in the array) and i want to know how i can insert elements in a 2D array in java as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues. You named that array `arr` (not `array`), and you did not size it at declaration time. Like,

```
int [][] array = new int[4][3];      
array[0][0] = 1;
array[0][1] = 10;
array[0][2] = 100;
array[1][1] = 99;
array[1][2] = 123;
array[1][0] = 177;
array[2][1] = 999;
array[2][2] = 453;
array[3][0] = 000;
array[3][1] = 1090;
array[3][2] = 1202;

for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < array[x].length; y++) {
        System.out.print(array[x][y]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: [JLS-10.3. Array Creation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3) leads to [§15.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) (your working example) and [**array initializer**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).